# Create table with 2000 column in oracle

Tags: oracle

Is is possible to create table in oracle with more than 2000 column. column name should be anything and type also should be anything.I dont know how to write that

Answer (score 15):

No, it is not possible.  Oracle has a [limit of 1000 columns per table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/limits003.htm).

Why would you want to create a table with 2000 columns in the first place, though?  That would strongly imply that your schema was in serious need of some normalization.  If you can explain the business problem you are trying to solve, we can almost certainly suggest a more appropriate solution.

If you are truly determined to violate proper normalization and you want to generate columns in a loop, you could do something like

```
DECLARE
  l_sql_stmt varchar2(1000);
BEGIN
  l_sql_stmt := 'CREATE TABLE violation_of_normalization( col1 number )';
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt;

  FOR i IN 2 .. 900
  LOOP
    l_sql_stmt := 'ALTER TABLE violation_of_normalization ADD( col' || i || ' number )';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql_stmt;
  END LOOP;
END;
```

It would be a very bad idea to do something like this but it is certainly possible.

Comment: atleast give me one example of 1000 column only.is there any way to run loop and create column

Comment: @DeepakKumar Don't you see? You can't even write code. Something is wrong in your design as Justin says.

Comment: @DeepakKumar instead of showing you how to do something you can't do, why don't you ask for a review on your design?

Comment: +1 nice table name :)

Comment: +1 for the table name. (Also, the answer is right, obviosuly)

Comment: @DeepakKumar - I updated my answer with an example of adding columns in a loop.  This is a very poor way to generate objects-- it violates basic principles of normalization-- and it makes very little sense.  It would be very helpful if you could explain the business problem you're trying to solve so that we can potentially suggest more appropriate solutions.